# Como puedo mantener el valor de la variable en PHP en un Paginador

Tags: php, session

Tengo problemas con `$_SESSION`, en mi código pierdo el valor de la misma, cuando paso a otra pagina por segunda vez, lo que me llama la atencion es que las flechas por la cual me desplazo siguen funcional, pero los `'li'` que me dicen la cantidad de paginas desaparecen, ya que dependen de `$_SESSION['total_pagina']`. Agradeceria cualquier ayuda que me puedan dar, hace unos dias que ando dando vuelta con este problemas. Gracias.

```
    <div class="paginador" >
            <ul>
                 <?php 
                    if(empty($_GET['pagina'])){
                        $pagina=1;
                     }else{
                        $pagina=$_GET['pagina'];
                     }

                         $porPagina=8;
                         $desde=($pagina-1) * $porPagina;
                         $total_paginas=ceil($total_registros / $porPagina);
                         $_SESSION['total_paginas']=$total_paginas;                                 
                ?>                                  
                    <li><a href="?pagina=<?php echo 1;?>">|<</a></li>
                    <li><a href="?pagina=<?php echo $pagina-1; ?>"><<</a></li>
                <?php                                                                                   
                        $totalPaginas=$_SESSION['total_paginas'];

                        if(empty($totalPaginas)){
                                echo 'la variable esta vacia';                                  
                            }else
                                {                                       
                                    echo 'no esta vacia'.$totalPaginas;
                                }

                    for($i=1; $i<=$totalPaginas; $i++)
                        {
                         $_SESSION['idClientes']=$idClientes ;                                                              

                            if($i==$pagina)
                                {
                                echo '<li class="pageSelected">'.$i.'</li>';                                            
                        }else{
                                echo '<li><a href="?pagina='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';    
                                }
                        }                               
                ?>                                                                          
                <li><a href="?pagina=<?php echo $pagina + 1;?>">>></a></li>
                <li><a href="?pagina=<?php echo $totalPaginas; ?>">>|</a></li>  
        </ul>                                       
    </div>                      
                    <div align="rigth"><input type="submit" id="botonMostrar" value="Mostrar" /></div>          
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La paginación se maneja siempre o al menos en el 99% de los casos mediante el `request`.

He creado un pequeño ejemplo con lo necesario para que lo puedas adaptar a tus necesidades.

```
<?php
    $max_pages = 10;
    $current_page = isset($_REQUEST['page']) ? $_REQUEST['page'] : 1; 
    $next_page_url = "/?page=" . ($current_page + 1);
    $previous_page_url = "/?page=" . ($current_page - 1);

    echo "ESTÁS VIENDO LA PAGINA N° $current_page <br/><br/>";

    if($current_page > 1){
        echo "<a href='$previous_page_url'>PAGINA ANTERIOR</a>";
    }else{
        echo "<a class='disable'>PAGINA ANTERIOR</a>";
    }
    echo ' - ';
    if($current_page < $max_pages){
        echo "<a href='$next_page_url'>PAGINA SIGUIENTE</a>";
    }else{
        echo "<a class='disable'>PAGINA SIGUIENTE</a>";
    }
```